# Limit of this special sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ sequence be defined as: $A_1 = 1,\; {A_n} = 1 - \exp(-A_{n-1}).$

How can I show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot A_n = 2$.

It is a sequence I came up with while working on something irrelevant and I could not find anything similar on the internet. Through Matlab, I can say that the limit is 2 but I am not sure why.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is a sequence I came up with while working on something irrelevant and I could not find anything similar on the internet. Through Matlab, I can say that the limit is 2 but I am not sure why.

Comment: Agreed. There is future in this post if you could write the context of this sequence and how you came up with it.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't matter what the initial value of $A_1$ is. If it is positive, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot A_n = 2$.

Another observation: ${A_n}$ is decreasing (we can prove it), while ${A_n}n$ seems to be increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this behavior is not surprising: we know that $1-e^{-x}\le x$ for all real $x$, with equality only for $x=0$.  If $A_1>0$, this means $0< A_n< A_{n-1}$, and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=0$. Now
$$A^{-1}_n-A^{-1}_{n-1}=\frac{A_{n-1}-1+e^{-A_{n-1}}}{A_{n-1}\,(1-e^{-A_{n-1}})},$$ and, using Taylor expansion or l'Hospital or what ever,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-1+e^{-x}}{x\,(1-e^{-x})}=\frac12.$$
Due to the Stolz–Cesàro theorem,
$$A^{-1}_n-A^{-1}_{n-1}\to\frac12$$ as $n\to\infty$ implies $$A^{-1}_n/n\to\frac12,$$ and that means $$n\cdot A_n\to2.$$